# Search an excel (or corresponding XML ) using DOM AJAX in PHP HTML for unique values

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

I have an excel file with list of records in few columns (on of the column   is 'year' ).
On the HTML page, if i give a range of years as a search input then it should search the excel file for all the records in that year range using PHP AJAX call and return back the selected rows.

Following are the things that i am thinking.
1. Convert entire excel sheet to XML file and use PHP AJAX DOM model to search the required records.
2. Simple HTML page with input search field and a button for AJAX call to PHP file on app. server

The problem is i don't want to search the entire file and check every records if the year falls in between the input year range since this will not be very efficient.

I am thinking of getting unique values of column 'year' of all the records in the excel sheet and convert them to year range and add the year range as an extra column and then search for this column with the input year range. But again this will search for all the records.

If in XML file, i have a node with year range then PHP AJAX code will only search the records under that node which matches the input year range. So how can i create such XML file from given excel file ?

```
Given excel file :  
year col2 col3        
1951  1    a  
1962  2    b                  
1974  3    c                  

XML of given excel file         
 <record>   
       <year>1950</year>
       <col2>1</col2>  
       <col3>a<col3> 
  </record>
 <record>...</record> 
    .....

Expected XML file for efficient searching for given input range
<year  = "1950-1960">
  <record>...</record>  <record>...</record>  <record>...</record>
</year = "1950-1960">

<year  = "1960-1970">
  <record>...</record>  <record>...</record>  <record>...</record>
</year = "1960-1970">
```

Any other ideas to this development?

Br
Nilesh

Comment: Where does the file come from? If efficiency is your goal, maybe you should simply build a btree index for each file upon upload / generation?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I finally managed to solve this using PHPExcel and some PHP logic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have dropped the idea and now storing the data in the Db tables.